# I have codeigniter in subdirectory and wordpress installed on root directory of my server

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

If i try to access `www.wordpress.com/codeigniter` it is getting redirected to `www.wordpress.com/en/codeigniter`. If i change rewriterule in the `.htaccess` of `wordpress` to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?codeigniter/(.*) /codeigniter/$1 [L]
```

> Getting 500 internal server error. The server encountered an
>   internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your
>   request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Help me out to get this done please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please try with this 

**RedirectMatch temp ^/codeigniter$ {HTTP_HOST}/codeigniter/**
**RewriteRule codeigniter$ /codeigniter/index.php [L]**

Comment: @PraveenKumar i added the above code now whole wordpress website is showing as 500 internal error

Comment: @PraveenKumar i changed the above code to two lines website is fine again i getting redirected to en/codeigniter

Comment: This code is working for you?

Comment: @beetlee  have you use any plugin in WordPress for language?

Comment: yes @PraveenKumar

Comment: code is not working for me but language plugin is used

Comment: for en in url "www.wordpress.com**/en/**codeigniter" came for WordPress language plugin please deactivate and check. Or check the plugin setting for redirect URL

Comment: i have been using the language plugin for admin subfolder